# Couldn't find Product with 'id'=test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Basically working on setting up a favorite product situation but I'm stuck on actually setting it up

This is what I got so far

I think it's because I'm using Friendly URL - I've added friendly.find.. but I still get another error there as well (see second image)

**Controller**

```rb
  def update
    khollection = Khollection.where(cproduct: Cproduct.find(params[:cproduct]), user: current_user)
    if khollection == []
        # Create the khollection
        Khollection.create(cproduct: Cproduct.find(params[:cproduct]), user: current_user)
        @khollection_exists = true
    else
        # Delete the khollection
        khollection.destory_all
        @khollection_exists = false
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {}
        format.js {}
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
<%= link_to 'Favorite', khollections_update_path(cproduct: @cproduct.title) %>
```

Below With Friendly .friendly.find(params...

```rb
  def update
    khollection = Khollection.where(cproduct: Cproduct.friendly.find(params[:cproduct]), user: current_user)
    if khollection == []
        # Create the khollection
        Khollection.create(cproduct: Cproduct.friendly.find(params[:cproduct]), user: current_user)
```

**MODEL**

```rb
class Khollection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cproduct
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Schema.rb**

```rb
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_05_28_112623) do

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.integer "record_id", null: false
    t.integer "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end

  create_table "cproducts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_cproducts_on_slug", unique: true
  end

  create_table "friendly_id_slugs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "slug", null: false
    t.integer "sluggable_id", null: false
    t.string "sluggable_type", limit: 50
    t.string "scope"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.index ["slug", "sluggable_type", "scope"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type_and_scope", unique: true
    t.index ["slug", "sluggable_type"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type"
    t.index ["sluggable_type", "sluggable_id"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_sluggable_type_and_sluggable_id"
  end

  create_table "khollections", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "Cproduct_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["Cproduct_id"], name: "index_khollections_on_Cproduct_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_khollections_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email"
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.text "full_company_logo"
    t.text "domain"
    t.string "business_name"
    t.string "tags"
    t.text "social_media"
    t.text "our_story"
    t.text "location_address"
    t.string "location_city"
    t.string "location_state"
    t.integer "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "admin"
    t.boolean "company"
    t.boolean "judge"
    t.boolean "blogger"
    t.string "username"
    t.string "slug"
    t.string "avatar"
    t.string "company_logo"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_users_on_slug", unique: true
  end


end
```

**CURRENT ERROR**
[image]

Comment: Try `<%= link_to 'Favorite', khollections_update_path(cproduct: @cproduct) %>`

Comment: Ok so without the friendly I get the following error: Couldn't find Cproduct with 'id'=test-55baa721-9e9a-42d7-8053-2b425fb5becb

with it i get the following error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: khollections.cproduct: SELECT "khollections".* FROM "khollections" WHERE "khollections"."cproduct" = ? AND "khollections"."user_id" = ?

I made your change as well @PavelMikhailyuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is where error is

```
create_table "khollections", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "Cproduct_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["Cproduct_id"], name: "index_khollections_on_Cproduct_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_khollections_on_user_id"
  end
```

replace with

```
create_table "khollections", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "cproduct_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["cproduct_id"], name: "index_khollections_on_cproduct_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_khollections_on_user_id"
  end
```

and

```
khollection = Khollection.where(cproduct: Cproduct.find_by(title: params[:cproduct]), user: current_user)



Khollection.create(cproduct: Cproduct.find_by(title: params[:cproduct]), user: current_user)


<%= link_to 'Favorite', khollections_update_path(cproduct: @cproduct.title) %>
```

Comment: Addded model to post see above

------- I Got this error now:   ---  ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in KhollectionsController#update
Cproduct(#70351925897280) expected, got "test-prod-2" which is an instance of String(#70351858327000)

Comment: Updated post with Schema,rb check above

Comment: Current Error ---

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in KhollectionsController#update
Couldn't find Cproduct with 'id'=another-product

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194051/discussion-between-bhupati-and-manuel-quintanilla).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going on behind the scenes with the friendly id, but you should be able to query by the product name:

```
  product = Cproduct.find_by(title: params[:cproduct]).take
  if product
    khollection = Khollection.where(cproduct_id: product.id), user: current_user).take
    if khollection.blank?
      # Create the khollection
      Khollection.create(cproduct: product, user: current_user)
      @khollection_exists = true
    else
      # Delete the khollection
      khollection.destory_all
      @khollection_exists = false
    end
  else
    # maybe return an error status "Product not found"
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.js {}
  end
```

The point is that you can always fall back on the column names instead of relying on a gem.